# PATH and CLASSPATH in Windows7 7 / Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

So I would like to set PATH and CLASSPATH system variables so I can use javac and java commands in the command line. I can just compile and run java programs in eclipse but I would also like to be able to run them through command line.

This is where I have Java installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
    jdk1.6.0_20
    jre6
```

And this is where eclipse stores my Java projects:

```
D:\java-projects
    HelloWorld
        bin
            HelloWorld.class
        src
            HelloWorld.java
```

I have set up the PATH and CLASSPATH variables like this:

```
PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin
CLASSPATH: D:\java-projects
```

But it doesn't work. When I write:

```
java HelloWorld
```

Or:

```
java HelloWorld.class
```

I get error like this:

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
```

The error is longer, that's just the first line.

How can I fix this? I'm mainly interested to be able to run compiled .class programs from the command line, I can do compiling in the eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classpath should point to "D:\java-projects\HelloWorld\bin".

Alternatively, you can specify your classpath with the "-cp" parameter instead of using an environment variable:

java -cp D:\java-projects\HelloWorld\bin HelloWorld

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the classpath to

```
d:\java-projects\bin
```

Currently you haven't got the "bin" part.

Note that `java HelloWorld.class` will never work - it's after the *class* name, not the *file* name.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CLASSPATH` doesn't point to the directory where the `class` file is located.

Answer (score 1):

Your classpath should point to D:/java-projects/bin

But instead I would invite you to use some build tools in order to manage your projects.
Have a look at ANT, Maven, Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PATH` environment variable should include the `bin` directory of your JDK installation directory. So you should add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin` to your `PATH`.

It's not advisable to set a permanent `CLASSPATH` environment variable, because it is a global setting that affects all Java programs that you run on your machine. If you don't set `CLASSPATH`, Java will by default only look in the current directory.

Instead of setting `CLASSPATH`, use the `-cp` or `-classpath` option on the `java` command, for example:

```
java -cp D:\java-projects\HelloWorld\bin HelloWorld
```

If you don't want to type that every time you want to run your program, put the command in a batch file (for example `hello.bat`), which you can then run by simply typing `hello`.